# Can anyone help in resolving the position:relative / z-index issue?

Tags: internet-explorer, z-index

I am developing this site http://ankiita.com/ihm/ where the black box that shows SEARCH BY LOCATION and stuff can be easily viewed in Chrome or Mozilla but on IE versions it stays below the slider. Can anybody help in resolving the issue? Is it related to z-index? position:relative?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928007/z-index-issue-in-ie-for-relative-position-element

Comment: Voting to close as not self-contained, especially since it refers to an external site to show what work has been done. It it is essentially too localised to one user.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a lower Z-index to the layers that are under the black-box. Older versions of IE needs to know the Z-index of each cumulative layers.

Like , you would set the z-index to 5 for your "slider", then for your black box, z-index to 10.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe it is a z-index issue, IE is not rendering this correctly. I'm using IE 11.

1. Set "#home2 #hero .slides" to "z-index: -1" or less.
2. Create a style for .search_main with "z-index: 1" or greater.
3. Remove the background for "#home2 #hero" - you may need to apply this back using a different class/ID. You may need to further define your ".search_main" with "background: #cccccc"